# Streaming audio to audio player in browser using content-range header not working as expected

Tags: html, audio, streaming

I have an app where a user can request to listen to some audio. Some of this audio could be very long, e.g. sometimes 16 hours, so i wanted to stream the audio to the html5 player, as otherwise the user will have to wait until the whole file is downloaded to their browser.

The back-end that is serving the audio is a Spring-boot service.

i have found that in both Chrome and Firefox, the player sends an open-ended range request:-

> Range: bytes=0-

I don't want to give the whole audio file at once as there is some back end processing required to create the big file, and so the request would time out, but if the request was for the first 1mb, then that would be fine, but unfortunately the browser isn't doing that.

So in my API, i am enforcing a 1mb restriction, and so my response will have these headers:-

> content-range: bytes 0-999999/28800329
> content-type: audio/mpeg
> content-length: 1000000

This initially appears to work fine, the chrome browser notices the 28800329 bytes and correctly displays in the player that this is a 2hr audio file, and starts playing, in the background, it starts sending requests to get the rest of the file, and as before, even if it requests:-

> Range: bytes=1000000-

i send it back:-

> content-range: bytes 1000000-1999999/28800329
> content-type: audio/mpeg
> content-length: 1000000

As i say, all looks fine, and when the player gets to the point in the audio when it needs the next chunk, it has it and plays on flawlessly. Unfortunately, the problem seems to be the seek bar. If I move the time slider to half way through the audio, it should be roughly 1hr in, but unfortunately just starts playing half way through the first chunk i sent it, i.e. from about 500,000 bytes onwards. It claims its 1h into the audio, but its not.

Firefox functionality is slightly worse, as it doesn't seem to use the 28800329 to define the length of the time bar, instead it just displays time as if the whole file was the first chunk (1mb), but when it reaches the end of that timeline, the time keeps going up and it continues to play.

i've tried setting content-length to the full size of the file on the server also, but no luck.